# How to edit grease pencil in regular 3d mode?

Tags: grease-pencil

I'm still adapting to the new way Blender handles grease pencil in 2.8.

I've used the grease pencil to sketch a front and profile view of a character I'm working on.  I'd like to duplicate this sketch and rotate one of the sketch layers 90 degrees so that I can view it in both front and side viewports.  However, none of the old UI for manipulating layers seems to still be there.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You can convert it to mesh and then try to apply the rotation?

Comment: I'm kind of confused what you're going for, wouldn't having the sketch rotated 90° and the view rotated 90° result in the same.. view? What am I missing?

Comment: I want to make a copy of the current drawing layer and then rotate the copy 90 degrees about Z.